# CSS Scale conflict with paddings

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` wrapping a thumb `img`. I applied an effect to scale and rotate the `img` when hovering the `div`. The problem is the div has a bootstrap class with padding-left, padding-right and when the image scales it removes that paddings, increasing the width of the image. How I can keep the paddings? You can see the example in the middle of the page of: https://lagaleramagazine.es

Example of 1 of the item:

```css
     .pt-cv-1-col img {
          -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
          transition: all 0.7s; 
    }
        
        
     .pt-cv-1-col:hover img {
          -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.3);
          -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.3);
          transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.3);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="event-56092" class="ect-list-post ect-featured-event  data-parent-post-id=" 56053""="">
     <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
      <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/50008823_1936412149789348_6701274349090897920_n-1024x715.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
       <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
        <div class="ect-list-date">
         <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule">
          <span class="ev-day">25</span>
          <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span>
          <span class="ev-yr">2019</span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ect-list-post-right">
      <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
       <div class="ect-list-description">
        <h2 class="ect-list-title">
         <a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores" rel="bookmark">VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores</a>
        </h2>
        <button class="btn1 button-more svg">Más detalles</button>
        <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
         <div class="ect-event-content">
          <p>Desde el lunes 21 de enero y hasta el martes 18 de junio, todos los socios de los Centros Municipales de Mayores que participan en la XXIII Campaña de Atención al Mayor, podrán inscribirse en las diferentes actividades de la VI Escuelas Deportivas para mayores. Se impartirán clases de pádel, tenis de mesa, petanca, rutas...</p>
          <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="p1-venue">
        <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue">
         <span class="ect-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </span>
         <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address">
          <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/lugar/area-de-atencion-al-mayor-ayuntamiento-de-badajoz/" title="Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz">Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz</a>,
          <span class="tribe-address">
           <span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span>
           <span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span>
           <abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr" title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr>
           <span class="tribe-country-name">España</span>
          </span>
         </span>
         <span class="ect-google">
          <a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Badajoz+Badajoz+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a>
         </span>
         <div class="ect-rate-area">
          <span class="ect-rate-icon">
           <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="ect-rate">Gratuito</span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't see no div or image within the class ( thumb-post ) in the code you provided?

Comment: Forget the thumb-post class, is from another div, I deleted them from the answer for avoiding mistakes.